# What is a spanning path in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, hamiltonian-path

I was reading graph theory by Frank Harary and he mentioned that a maximal non-Hamiltonian graph will have every two vertex joined by a spanning path. Is a spanning path just another name for a Hamiltonian path?

Comment: Is it in the context of Minimum Spanning Trees?

Comment: It is in context to a theorem for sufficient condition regarding the existence of a Hamilton cycle by posa. l.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Page 11:

> A *spanning subgraph* is a subgraph containing all the points of $G$

Therefore a spanning path is a path containing all the points of $G$, which is a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

In general given any graph $G=(V,E)$ a subgraph $H\subseteq G$ spans $G$ if and only if $V(H)=V(G)$. Therefore if $G$ contains a path graph $P$ we must have $V(P)=V(G)$ so the path runs through every vertex in $G$ and must be a hamoltonian path.